# Standard way of finding a inverse Laplace transform

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, definite-integrals, exponential-function, laplace-transform

Is there a standard procedure to find this inverse Laplace transform? $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\int_\text{a}^\text{b}f(t)e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\dots\tag1$$

Where $\text{a}$ and $\text{b}$ are real and positive.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo How can I find the inverse Laplace transform of the function that I stated in equation $(1)$, for any function $f(t)$ and any constants $a$ and $b$, assuming that the integral exists?!

Comment: Your function is the Laplace transform of $f \cdot p$, where $p$ is a unit rectangular pulse on $[a,b]$ (and zero otherwise). Hence, the inverse Laplace transform is...

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I've no idea ..... ?!

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Maybe that I'm stupid, but I do not see it

Comment: $$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left( \int_a^b f(t) e^{-s t} \mathrm{d} t \right) = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left( \int_0^{\infty} f(t) p (t) e^{-s t} \mathrm{d} t \right) =  \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left(  \mathcal{L} (f \cdot p) \right) = f \cdot p$$